# Redirecting not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

So here's what I want to do. I want to check if the userid in segment(3) exist or else it will redirect somewhere instead of still loading the view with an error.

Here's the example url

```
 http://localhost/ems/edit_user/edit_user_main/1001
```

Now if I try to edit the userid in segment(3) and intentionally put an invalid userid, it still loads the view and i don't know why

Here's my function

```
public function edit_user_main(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $check = $this->get_data->check_if_exist($id);
    if($check) {
        $data['title'] = 'Edit User';
        $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('usertoedit');
        $this->load->model('accounts/get_data');   
        $item = $this->get_data->get_user($id);
        $data['user'] = $item[0];
        $data['main_content'] = 'edit_user/edit_user_main';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    } else {
        redirect('admin/adminuser');
    }
}
```

Here's the model

```
public function check_if_exist($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('accounts',array('user_id'=>$id));
    if($query) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

There is no problem with the fetching of data.
The problem is even if the userid doesn't exist, the view is still loading but with an error coz there's no data for that userID. It's not redirecting,

I tried using print_r and it working fine, the value of the $check is 1 when there's a valid userID.

Hope someone can help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With your function it will always return true because the statement

`$this->db->get_where('accounts',array('user_id'=>$id));`

will always execute,So you need to check query is returning any result row or not with the statement

`$query->num_rows()`.

```
public function check_if_exist($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('accounts',array('user_id'=>$id));
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){ //change made here
       return TRUE;
    }
    else{
       return FALSE;
   }
}
```